# Indesign Catalog with data merge

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, file-format, data-merge, microsoft-excel

i'm working on a tools catalog made in CorelDRAW but i want to move it in Indesign. The catalog is separated by multiple categories from mechanical tools to wood and plastic products, electrical and so on (~5000 products plus products that have different characteristics).

What i want to do:
-i want to make a database in excel with fields and add those fields in the Indesign template.

My problem:
-how do i make indesign to add automatically the number of lines for products with more characteristics?

Here is an example:
[image]

Some products have one characteristic and some products have 20 or more

Comment: I would use dedicated plugin for catalog creation or one for managing linked excel files. Using data merge would, from top of my head,  require creating template with max amount or lines and then, after creation, remove of the unncesessary ones.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of plugins that do similar things? And creating the template with maximum amount  and removing would align the cells?

Comment: I use InCatalog from emsoftware http://emsoftware.com/products/emcatalog/ i you use

Answer (score 3):

This is quite technical and not possible using the built-in Data Merge logic. By default, Data Merge will only work with a specific number of table rows, and does not create 'as many table rows as needed'.